# Discord embed list

Tags: discord, discord.js

I want to print an embed item list but the empty spaces(blank field titles) between each item are bothering me and making it unnecessarily long. 
So is there a way to print all the items from an array without having to keep adding new fields?

```
const list = new Discord.MessageEmbed()
.setTitle('Items')
.setColor('#0099ff')
for (var xc = 0; xc < (items.length-1); xc++)
{
        var item = items[xc];
        list.addField('\u200B',item);
}
msg.channel.send(list);
```

This is what I have at the moment.

Answer (score 0):

Maybe set it as the description

```js
list.setDescription(items.join("\n"));
```

Comment: ah, so that would work.
I would consider using that but what if my array has 1000 indexes?

Comment: If that array joined passed the character limit, you could trunicate it, or if you don't wanna lose data you'll have to send multiple messages.